# When should I NOT use Units of Measure?

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

**When should I NOT use Units of Measure?**

I feel that any values that are used in calculations should have a unit of measure applied to it.

**Are my thoughts accurate?**

**If they are, then why doesn't F# by default enforce this constraint to encourage correctness?**

In my case, I used Units of Measure for a basketball game:

For example:

```
[<Measure>] type pts
type Player = { Score:int<pts> }
```

Here's the model that leverages units of measure:

```
(*Types*)
[<Measure>] type pts
type Player = { Score:int<pts> }

type FieldShot = TwoPointer| ThreePointer
type FoulShots = FoulShot  | TwoFoulShots | ThreeFoulShots

type FoulShooter  = FoulShooter  of Player
type FieldShooter = FieldShooter of Player

(*Functions*)
let shoot (lastShot:int<pts>) player =
    (player.Score + lastShot)

let fieldShot (fieldShooter, shot) =

    let player = match fieldShooter with
                 | FieldShooter player -> player

    match player.Score with
    | score when score > 10<pts> -> score
    | _ ->  match (fieldShooter, shot) with
            | FieldShooter player, shot -> match shot with
                                           | TwoPointer   -> player |> shoot 2<pts>
                                           | ThreePointer -> player |> shoot 3<pts>
let foulShot (foulShooter, shot) =

    let player = match foulShooter with
                 | FoulShooter player -> player

    match player.Score with
    | score when score >= 11<pts> -> score
    | _ ->  match (foulShooter, shot) with
            | FoulShooter player, shot -> match shot with
                                          | FoulShot       -> player |> shoot 1<pts>
                                          | TwoFoulShots   -> player |> shoot 2<pts>
                                          | ThreeFoulShots -> player |> shoot 3<pts>

let makeFoulShots foulShots (shooter, defender) = 
    FieldShooter { Score= foulShot (shooter, foulShots) }, defender

let makeFieldShot fieldBasket (shooter, defender) =
    FoulShooter { Score= fieldShot (shooter, fieldBasket) }, defender

let turnover (shooter, defender) = (defender, shooter)

(*Client*)
let player1, player2 = FieldShooter { Score=0<pts> } ,
                       FieldShooter { Score=0<pts> }

let results = (player1, player2) |> makeFieldShot TwoPointer
                                 |> makeFoulShots ThreeFoulShots
                                 |> makeFieldShot TwoPointer
                                 |> makeFoulShots TwoFoulShots
                                 |> makeFieldShot TwoPointer
                                 |> makeFoulShots FoulShot
```

Comment: I believe in your case using UOM doesn't bring anything useful to the program because you don't make calculations with different units. It could be useful if you had values representing length in <inches> and <centimeters> for example.

Comment: Would it be over-engineering if I used UOM as a prevention mechanism for maintenance errors if the program were to be extended? Or does YAGNI apply?

Comment: Don't know what YAGNI is but yes, I believe it would be overkill

Comment: You Aint Going to Need It

Comment: UOM can be useful (outside of simulations) for when numbers have some additional metadata - for example screen/paper coordinates.  One thing could be to differentiate points scored in different ways.  But you always want at least two different types of numbers or you are just wasting your time

Comment: units will also be erased so if you interoperate or need them at runtime you're out of luck:
Units at Runtime

Units of measure are used for static type checking. When floating point values are compiled, the units of measure are eliminated, so the units are lost at run time. Therefore, any attempt to implement functionality that depends on checking the units at run time is not possible. For example, implementing a ToString function to print out the units is not possible.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if F# is not the language you should be using to learn functional programming. As I noted F# is constrained in what it can do because of being implemented with .NET and coming from OCaml. This is not a bad thing, you just have to be aware of what it can and can not do when creating solutions. While I don't know Haskell, but plan to, maybe you should learn Haskell and then come back to F#. Many of the best F# programmers I know also know Haskell.

Comment: I've come too far to abandon ship now. Hence, I have invested too much of my free time in this technology. Thus, I figure I have another six months until I become competent in F#. Once, I establish comfort with F#, I will visit Scala.

Comment: @ScottNimrod No, I don't feel it would be over-engineering to put in units of measure as a prevention mechanism. Adding units costs you barely anything - note that, in your example, you could have omitted pretty much all of the `<pts>` and replaced with `<_>`. In more realistic code, you won't even see the `<_>` often. I have to admit that I am a huge fan of units-of-measure (I maintain a huge F# codebase), and units have saved the day on countless occasions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If they are, then why doesn't F# by default enforce this constraint to encourage correctness?

For one, because it needs to interoperate with languages which don't support units of measure. If you want to use values coming from a C# library method in a computation, how can it decide what unit to use? Even if F# developers spend a lot of time annotating all the standard library methods with units of measure, this wouldn't help with third-party libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the only answer that springs to mind is that you should generally not use unit of measures for [dimensionless quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity).

Consider values such as pi or *e*.

Dimensionless values often arise from ratios of quantities that do have some physical dimension.

Consider you want to create some program logic that triggers when one team's basket ball score reaches double the score of another team, you would need a dimensionless quantity:

```
if teamBScore >= 2 * teamAScore then
    ...
else
    ...
```

The value `2` has to be used in a calculation and has to be dimensionless or the units of `teamAScore` and `teamBScore` wouldn't match.

Of course, strictly speaking you could annotate such values with units of `1` explicitly but that's probably overkill.

Aside from that, the rest of the question is primarily opinion based.  You should use or not use units of measure depending on how you assess the gain in safety you'll get at the cost of (slightly) increased programming time and verbosity.

Comment: "Well, the only answer that springs to mind is that you should definitely not use unit of measure for dimensionless quantities." Definitely? No. Angle is a dimensionless quantity, but this isn't a reason not to distinguish degrees and radians (or also dimensionless moles from either of them!).

Comment: John Palmer's comment on the question gives another example of usefully applying UOM to dimensionless qualities (if you consider screen coordinates as number of pixels rather than length).

Comment: Good points, definitely valid use cases for dimensionless quantities using units of measure. I think this remains a decent guideline though, while you might use moles as a unit of measure I think it would be an unusual step to use, e.g. thousands as an explicit unit.